# NLog LogManager.LogFactory.Flush during ServiceBase.OnStop

Tags: c#, windows, logging, service, nlog

I have some NLog log targets that are wrapped inside `AsyncTargetWrapper` instances in my Windows service application. When `ServiceBase.OnStop()` is called, I want to ensure that `LogManager.Flush(15000)` has 15 seconds to flush any cached messages to the log targets by calling `ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime(15000)`. But which should come first? Do I call `Flush()` and then `RequestAdditionalTime()`, or vice-versa?

Do I do THIS:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    // Tell NLog to flush; give it 15 seconds:
    LogManager.Flush(15000);

    // Ask the Service Control Manager not to mark us unresponsive for 15 seconds:
    RequestAdditionalTime(15000);
}
```

Or do I do THIS:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    // Ask the Service Control Manager not to mark us unresponsive for 15 seconds:
    RequestAdditionalTime(15000);

    // Tell NLog to flush; give it 15 seconds:
    LogManager.Flush(15000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `LogManager.Flush` could take 15 seconds in your example, I would recommend to first request the additional time. So:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    // Ask the Service Control Manager not to mark us unresponsive for 15 seconds:
    RequestAdditionalTime(15000);

    // Tell NLog to flush; give it 15 seconds:
    LogManager.Flush(15000);
}
```

Or maybe even better:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    // Ask the Service Control Manager not to mark us unresponsive for 15 seconds:
    RequestAdditionalTime(15100); // 100 extra ms

    // Tell NLog to flush; give it 15 seconds:
    LogManager.Flush(15000);
}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Where I was getting hung up is that I haven't been able to make Flush() take more that a few seconds no matter how many cached log entries I pile onto the stack, so it wasn't clear to me whether Flush() was happening asynchronously or not. But yes, requesting the additional time first and THEN flushing makes sense. Thanks!